# Empty NSCFConstantString in stored UserDefaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I have a problem with a stored userDefaults array.

I have a simple object (in the image I have cut off some variables) with two strings mutableArray.

When I save this object in the userDefaults I have the same object in the top (of the image), the problem occurs when I retrieve the object; I have the object in the bottom (added by me in a mutableArray, same object before add it).

[image]

the problem is that I make comparisons between objects and it returns false because there is an empty `NSCFConstantString` in the second array.

These are the two methods to store and retrieve the object in the userDefaults:

```
- (void)saveCustomObject:(NSMutableArray *)object key:(NSString *)key
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:object] forKey:key];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

- (NSArray *)loadCustomObjectWithKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *dataRepresentingSavedArray = [currentDefaults objectForKey:key];
    NSMutableArray *objectArray = nil;

    if (dataRepresentingSavedArray != nil)
    {
        NSArray *savedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingSavedArray];
        if (savedArray != nil)
            objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:savedArray];
        else
            objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return objectArray;
}
```

I would prefer not to have to write logic to handle this empty string.

Where is it coming from?

Comment: Please show the code you are using to save and load the array

Comment: Ooook. See the edit.

Comment: Please show the `NSCoding` methods for your `MenuItem` class. Also, there is no need to call `synchronize`. You could also set `objectArray = [savedArray mutableCopy];`

Comment: Also, it isn't good practice to return a mutable array from a method that says it returns an immutable array. Either change the method signature or return an immutable array and leave it up to the caller to make a mutable copy if required.